# How to get remoteAddress() of NIO DatagramChannel

Tags: java, nio

I am writing some client code using NIO to listen for UDP packets from multiple servers (many of which are configured to reply to the same port). I failed in my attempt to have dedicated channels to each known server [NIO. 2 clients binding to same port, only 1 can read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753293/nio-2-clients-binding-to-same-port-only-1-can-read).

So I am now trying to bind to a port without specifying a destination

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.configureBlocking(false);
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

My selector now successfully receives all UDP packets directed to this port from all my servers

```
...    
  SelectionKey selKey = it.next();
  if (selKey.isValid() && selKey.isReadable()) {
    DatagramChannel sChannel = (DatagramChannel) selKey.channel();
    sChannel.getRemoteAddress();//My problem lies here
 ....
```

As expected sChannel.getRemoteAddress() returns null because I didnt configure it. So how do I determine where this packet originated?

Answer (score 1):

The source address of a DatagramPacket is in the packet. See the Javadoc. Or, if you connect the DatagramChannel or its underlying DatagramSocket, you can get it from there ... but not otherwise.

Comment: Actually, the `receive` method returns the address.

Answer (score 1):

To get remote address of a sender, you need to perform data receiving like this:

```
if (key.isReadable()) {
    ByteBuffer byte_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(buffer_size);
    InetSocketAddress remote_address = (InetSocketAddress) ((DatagramChannel)key.channel()).receive(byte_buffer);
    byte_buffer.flip();
}
```

As you can see, ***receive*** method of the ***DatagramChannel*** class returns sender's address.

Answer (score 1):

getRemoteAddress() will return null on DatagramChannel connection.

I used the following code :

```
//Declare the client address to be any random value, Just for initialization                
InetSocketAddress clientAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",1000);
//Declare the clientaddress' buffer 
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(255);
// Receive from the buffer
clientAddress = (InetSocketAddress)clientChannel.receive(buffer);
//This address is retained by masking receive 
System.out.println("Client address : " + clientAddress);
```